# loop stuck on first page

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting, beautifulsoup

Been using beautiful soup to iterate through pages, but for whatever reason I can't get the loop to advance beyond the first page.  it seems like it should be easy because it's a text string, but it seems to loop back, maybe it's my structure not my text string?

Here's what I have:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('nhlstats.csv', "w")


groups=['points', 'shooting', 'goaltending', 'defensive', 'timeonice', 'faceoffs', 'minor-penalties', 'major-penalties']

year = ["2016", "2015","2014","2013","2012"]

for yr in year:
    for gr in groups:
        url = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/year/"+str(yr)
    #www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/year/2014/
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    pagecount = soup.findAll(attrs= {"class":"page-numbers"})[0].string
    pageliteral = int(pagecount[5:])
    for i in range(0,pageliteral):
        number = int(((i*40) + 1))
        URL = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/"+str(yr) + "/count/"+str(number)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        for tr in soup.select("#my-players-table tr[class*=player]"):
            row =[]
            for ob in range(1,15):
                player_info = tr('td')[ob].get_text(strip=True)
                row.append(player_info)
            f.write(str(yr) +","+",".join(row) + "\n")

f.close()
```

this gets the same first 40 records over and over.

I tried using [this solution](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) as an if and did find that doing

```
prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="nofollow"]')[0]
newurl =  "http:" + prevLink.get('href')
```

did work better, but I'm not sure how to do the loop in such a way that it advances? possibly just tired but my loop there still just goes to the next set of records and gets stuck on *that* one. please help me fix my loop

**UPDATE**

my formatting was lost in the copy paste, my actual code looks like:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('nhlstats.csv', "w")


groups=['points', 'shooting', 'goaltending', 'defensive', 'timeonice', 'faceoffs', 'minor-penalties', 'major-penalties']

year = ["2016", "2015","2014","2013","2012"]


for yr in year:
    for gr in groups:
        url = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/year/"+str(yr)
    #www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/year/2014/
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        pagecount = soup.findAll(attrs= {"class":"page-numbers"})[0].string
        pageliteral = int(pagecount[5:])
        for i in range(0,pageliteral):
            number = int(((i*40) + 1))
            URL = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/"+str(yr) + "/count/"+str(number)
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
            for tr in soup.select("#my-players-table tr[class*=player]"):
                row =[]
                for ob in range(1,15):
                    player_info = tr('td')[ob].get_text(strip=True)
                    row.append(player_info)
                f.write(str(yr) +","+",".join(row) + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: I cannot see how you get the first page at all. Is that exactly how your code looks?

Comment: The Indent error that folks are commenting on is actually just lost formatting from my copy paste into stackoverflow... updating with actual formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code indenting was mostly at fault. Also it would be wise to actually use the CSV library you imported, this will automatically wrap the player names in quotes to avoid any commas inside from ruining the csv structure.

This works by looking for the link to the next page and extracting the starting count. This is then used to build your the next page get. If no next page can be found, it moves to the next year group. Note, the count is not a page count but a starting entry count.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


groups= ['points', 'shooting', 'goaltending', 'defensive', 'timeonice', 'faceoffs', 'minor-penalties', 'major-penalties']
year = ["2016", "2015", "2014", "2013", "2012"]

with open('nhlstats.csv', "wb") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for yr in year:
        for gr in groups:
            start_count = 1
            while True:
                #print "{}, {}, {}".format(yr, gr, start_count)     # show progress

                url = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/{}/count/{}".format(yr, start_count)
                page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

                for tr in soup.select("#my-players-table tr[class*=player]"):
                    row = [yr]
                    for ob in range(1, 15):
                        player_info = tr('td')[ob].get_text(strip=True)
                        row.append(player_info)

                    csv_output.writerow(row)

                try:
                    start_count = int(soup.find(attrs= {"class":"page-numbers"}).find_next('a')['href'].rsplit('/', 1)[1])
                except:
                    break
```

Using `with` will also automatically close your file at the end.

This would give you a csv file starting as follows:

```
2016,"Patrick Kane, RW",CHI,82,46,60,106,17,30,1.29,287,16.0,9,17,20
2016,"Jamie Benn, LW",DAL,82,41,48,89,7,64,1.09,247,16.6,5,17,13
2016,"Sidney Crosby, C",PIT,80,36,49,85,19,42,1.06,248,14.5,9,10,14
2016,"Joe Thornton, C",SJ,82,19,63,82,25,54,1.00,121,15.7,6,8,21
```

Comment: This worked great! I made a few mods:

1) I added in a variable for the sort column since points wasn't consistent across columns.

2) I ended up doing raw_input for each variable since otherwise it would loop across each item for each key pair. This also had the side benefit of not throwing in goalies.

minor notes:
1) can you explain how the page jumps worked? they were perfect, curious how it worked so I can learn.

2)I actually did want the names unquoted so it would split on comma and create a column for position once I open the csv. is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: The site displays `1 of 20` but the required url is a count. So IF 50 entries were on page one, page two would start with the url having 51. The code looks for this in the url following the `page-numbers` class. In theory the whole url code be used instead.

Comment: If you unquote the csv entries, there will be a variable number of columns, so the data will never align properly if opened in Excel for example. You could add `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='', quotechar=''` to the writer parameters to disable quoting. It would make reading the file back in very difficult. A `csv.reader()` would automatically parse and remove the quoting if you read it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the URL many times before you are opening it the first time, due to an indentation error. Try this:

`for gr in groups:
        url = "...some_url..."
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        ...everything else should be indented....`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately as noted that was a copy/paste error.  actual code re-posted